# Why does b['x'] || 0 evaluate when x || 0 does not...and both are undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
: a = {a: 1, b: 2}
    Object {a: 1, b: 2}

: b = {a: 0, b: a['c'] || 0}
    Object {a: 0, b: 0}

: c = {a: 0, b: d || 0}
    ReferenceError: d is not defined

: a['c']
    undefined
```

I guess I'm asking what the difference between `not defined` and `undefined` is?

Is this the right way to handle this kind of situation?

```
return {
            resLength : retRes.length,
            id : (typeof browser.id === 'undefined') ? 0 : browser.id,
       }
```

Comment: There is a fallacy here. `a` *was* previously defined so it is different than d. If you change `a['c']` to `someUndefinedName['c']` you will see the same ReferrenceError.

Comment: What's the difference between undefined and not defined though? is it that `a.c` could exist, whereas `d` could not?

Comment: @Cory, I know that ... I was showing that neither attribute had a value, simply that one is given undefined and the other not defined.

Comment: what about `(browser.hasOwnProperty('id')) ? browser.id : 0;`?, for check object has property or not?

Comment: The difference here is accessing an undefined *variable* versus accessing an undefined *property*.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, ahhh..thank you. I think, `id : (!browser) ? 0 : browser.id` is what I'm looking for. Thanks guys.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Exactly. `d` is an undefined variable; `a` **is** defined, but the `a.c` property is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a matter of the language's semantics. Accessing an object property that doesn't exist evaluates to `undefined`. Accessing a variable that doesn't exist raises a `ReferenceError`.

The language could be designed such that accessing a variable that doesn't exist evaluates to `undefined`, but it isn't, thank god.

It could also be designed so accessing an object property that doesn't exist raises a `PropertyReferenceError` or something, but it isn't.

---

As an aside, to check whether a variable is defined, you can check whether `typeof varname === 'undefined'`. That's another convention - you can stick non-existent variables in a `typeof` and the `typeof` will evaluate to `'undefined'` instead of throwing a `ReferenceError`.

If you're in the global scope, you can also check whether `this.varname === undefined`, since then the property-access rules apply.